# Request with JSON parameters throwing Uncaught (in promise) Syntax Error

Tags: javascript, json, express, post, fetch-api

I'm using Fetch to make a post request to my server and I'm trying to pass some information along with it, as shown below.

```js
var rating = document.getElementById("rating");
var ratingValue = rating.innerHTML;
fetch("/films",{
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        rated : ratingValue
    })
})
```

When I try to access this information in my server I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

The server side code is:

```js
app.post("/films", function(req,res){
    var rating = req.body.rated;
    ...
})
```

And it's this first line in the function that is giving me the error, the one declaring the `rating` variable.

Comment: I don't really see how this could be happening, unless your real code is different from the sample code you shared. Does your exact sample code work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `var rating = document.getElementById("rating");` is an html element that looks something like this `<div id='rating'>Some text</div>`. I do not know whats in the `rating` element, or the type so this is just an example. Later on in your code you're using `rating` as the key in

```
 body: JSON.stringify({
        rating : ratingValue
 })
```

so your trying to create a key:value pair along the lines of

```
{ "<div id='rating'>Some Text</div>" : ratingValue }
```

Seeing as the error is showing a < symbol at position 0, and your key has a < at position 0, I'm thinking that may be what is causing your error. Are you trying to use the value that is in the rating element as the key for your body?

****Update 5-25-2020****

If the html element with the id='rating' has a nested element in it, that may be the problem if you are only wanting a primitive value.

```
//This would cause a problem as the innerHTML of 'rating' is <p>10</p>
<div id='rating'>
     <p>10</p>
</div>
```

The example below should work as long as your 'ratingValue' is expecting a number, and the innerHTML of 'rating' is 10. You may need to parseInt() the innerHTML, but try it without first.

```
<div id='rating'>
     10
</div>
```

This is just an example as I don't know what type of element the 'rating' Id is attached to.

Comment: sorry i made a mistake copying code across, even when i use a different word for the key (as i've now done in the edited code above) i get returned the same errror.

Comment: Okay I see what you are doing, be sure that your html element with the rating Id does not have a nested html element in it as well. Ill edit my comment to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you mean `req.body.rating`?

Comment: actually got the title wrong when making the request, request should have been rated : ratingValue. I've corrected the code above to show this. Error is still the same though

Comment: Can you what's inside your element rating?